# String as Document

Tags: java, document

I'm following this turorial on parsing XML with XPath, and it gives the following example to open a document:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
domFactory.setNamespaceAware(true); // never forget this!
DocumentBuilder builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = builder.parse("books.xml");
```

What I would like to do, is change that so that the `Document` is reading a `String` variable that I already have made, instead of reading from a file. How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader("<some><xml></xml></some>")));
```

Answer (score 2):

Look [here](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0573.html)

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf =
        DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    InputSource is = new InputSource();
    is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xmlRecords));

    Document doc = db.parse(is);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this one:

```
public static Document stringToDom(String xmlSource) 
        throws SAXException, ParserConfigurationException, IOException {
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    return builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlSource)));
}
```